# ElasticSearch return aggregation AND field value

Tags: elasticsearch

Let’s say that each document in my ES index has following fields:

```
ASIN, name, referenceNumber, videoViews, timeWatched
```

There can be **many documents with the same ASIN** fields.

I’m doing teams aggregation, that aggregate documents in my ES cluster based on **ASIN field**. 
This Aggregation counts sum of **videoViews** and sum of **timeWatched** **for each ASIN bucket**.

ElasticSearch returns aggregation response where **ASIN** - a key for each bucket, and sum of **timeWatched** and sum of**videoViews** are values for this key.

My simple question is how to make aggregation return **name** and **referenceNumber** as well? If I know that documents with same **ASIN** will have same **name** and **referenceNumber**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch terms aggs work in many ways similar to a SQL Group by, so you could for instance do multiple levels of aggs, ex. ASIN -> name -> referencenumber. This will also cover cases where you have different names with same ASIN etc.

```
{
    "aggs": {
       "AsinAgg": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "ASIN", "size":0
          },
          "aggs": {
              "nameAgg": {
                 "terms": {
                      "field": "name", "size": 0
                  },
                  "aggs" {.....}
              }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Another way can be to use the top_hits within an agg and return the top 1 hit. If you are sure they have the same name and referenceNumber, you should be ok with just getting a single top hit. I would not recommend doing this even though it could work in specific cases. Read up on top_hits here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend using top_hits? Seems to be the perfect match in a use case I am currently working on.